# Can ssh -X render a opengl 4+ window?

Tags: nvidia, ssh, opengl, x11-forwarding

I would like to render a GUI of open3d and it is written in OpenGL 4.1. The GUI renders well on the remote machine from desktop and `glxinfo` tells me I and OpenGL version of 4.6 for Ubuntu 20.04.

However, when I tried to connect to my remote server from WSL2, MobaXTerm, or another Ubuntu, I cannot render the GUI and `glxinfo -B` tells me I only have OpenGL 3.1 Mesa.

Is it possible to do `ssh -X` or other connection approach with OpenGL 4+ enabled?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using, it does matter.

Comment: @David. The remote machine is 20.04. The local machine is WSL2/MobaXTerm/Ubuntu 20.04